# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Broadcast already finished

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fatal-error, broadcast, firebase-crash-reporting

I am getting this below fatal crash from the firebase Crashlytics. here are the details logs. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this issue?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Broadcast already finished
   at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult.sendFinished(BroadcastReceiver.java:248)
   at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult$1.run(BroadcastReceiver.java:221)
   at android.app.QueuedWork.processPendingWork(QueuedWork.java:258)
   at android.app.QueuedWork.-wrap0()
   at android.app.QueuedWork$QueuedWorkHandler.handleMessage(QueuedWork.java:278)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: We need to see some of your code.

Comment: I am getting the very same crashes reported, and also don't know which code may causing this. So I fully understand why there are no other code snippets in the question. For me it is happening only on "Vivo" devices. Is this a system bug?

Comment: @petin this issue got resolved for me I was facing this issue because of some third-party library. Please refer this https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-android-sdk/issues/395

Comment: @tech.mohit.garg I am not using 3rd party libraries which may cause this. Rather I think that it may be caused either by admob or by firebase. Unfortunately I can not isolate the issue.

Comment: It's an open issue. See this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/257513022